# VBA - Action on workbook 2 after saving workbook 1

Tags: vba, excel

So,here's my problem :
I have a macro in VBA which delete all hidden columns in my sheet. It work properly.

```
Sub Test()
Dim F As Integer, C As Integer
For F = 1 To Sheets.Count
    ActiveSheet.Select
    For C = 15 To 2 Step -1
        ActiveSheet.Columns(C).Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        derniereligne = ActiveCell.Row
        If ActiveSheet.Columns(C).Hidden = True Then
            ActiveSheet.Columns(C).Delete
        End If
    Next C
Next F
End Sub
```

But now, my project evolved, and I must save my workbook on a copy so I did it :

```
Sub SaveXL()

Dim Nom2 As String
Dim Jour2 As String
Dim FPath2 As String
Jour2 = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd - h\hmm'")
Nom2 = Jour2 & " Pricelist"
FPath2 = Sheets("PARAM").Range("B33").Value
On Error GoTo fin4
fichier = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FPath2 & Nom2, "Fichiers Excel (*.xls), *.xls")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs fichier
Exit Sub
fin4:MsgBox "La création de l'excel a échoué"
End Sub
```

It create me a copy, ok. But I want to use the first macro (Test) on the copy of my first workbook (Workbook 2) when I save with the 2nd macro (SaveXL).

Is it possible ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: You want to run the macro Test() every time SaveXL() runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In SaveXL call Test and pass the name of the copied workbook:

```
fichier = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FPath2 & Nom2, "Fichiers Excel (*.xls), *.xls")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs fichier
Test Nom2
```

> In Test check if the target workbook is opened. Open if it is not open, run the macro and close it with save changes equal to True:

```
Sub Test(targetWorkbookName As String)
    Dim F As Integer, C As Integer, derniereligne

    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks(targetWorkbookName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If (targetWorkbook Is Nothing) Then _
        Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(targetWorkbookName)

    For F = 1 To Sheets.Count
        ActiveSheet.Select
        For C = 15 To 2 Step -1
            ActiveSheet.Columns(C).Select
            Selection.End(xlDown).Select
            derniereligne = ActiveCell.Row
            If ActiveSheet.Columns(C).Hidden = True Then
                ActiveSheet.Columns(C).Delete
            End If
        Next C
    Next F

    targetWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
End Sub
```

*Hope I understood it correctly. HTH*

Comment: it work, thanks. But when I changed the name of my file, it doesn't execute the macro on the file because it's no "Nom2" anymore... How can I fix the problem, do you have an idea ? (Sorry for answer time)

Comment: `Nom2` is varable which should contain the name of the copied workbook. This varaible is used inside of `SaveXL`. What name of what file did you change? Please explain it more in detail.

Comment: In fact, like you said, `Nom2` is a variable which contain the name used for prefilling the name of the worksheet which is saved thanks to `SaveXL`.
But, when I changed the name prefilled on the saving window, `Test` don't work. For example : If `Nom2` = Hello, when `SaveXL` ask me to save the worksheet, "Hello" appear on the field "Name of file". 
If I change this saving name for "Hi", the file is saved with the name "Hi", but didn't execute `Test` because the parameter is not `Nom2` (Hello) but "Hi"... I hope it's clear, because my english is not very good... :/

Comment: I see :). In that case you will have to extract the actual name from the variable `fichier`. This variable contains the full path and at the end the workbook name. So extract the workbook name and pass it to `Test`.

Comment: I tried with `Test ThisWorkbook.Name`, but I don't know how to select the copy of my actual workbook :/

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs fichier` saves the active workbook but it didn't change the active workbook and the copy is not opened. `ThisWorkbook.Name` is name of the workbook where the macro is located, not of the copied workbook. To get the name of the copied book parse the `fichier` variable and get so the name you entered in the `GetSaveAsFileName` dialog.

Comment: Ok, I understood, I used this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a99s8akf(v=vs.84).aspx
It worked. Thanks a lot for your patience and your help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a workbook as a parameter on you sub Test(). So, when after you save your workbook, you run the Test sub in your new workbook. 
Look at the modification that I made in your Test() code:

```
'Here I insert a parameter to your sub
Sub Test(myWorkBook as Workbook)
    Dim F As Integer, C As Integer
    For F = 1 To myWorkBook.worksheets.Count
        'ActiveSheet.Select
        For C = 15 To 2 Step -1
            myWorkBook.worksheets(f).Columns(C).Select
            Selection.End(xlDown).Select
            derniereligne = ActiveCell.Row
            If myWorkBook.worksheets(f).Columns(C).Hidden = True Then
                myWorkBook.worksheets(f).Columns(C).Delete
            End If
        Next C
    Next F
End Sub
```

Now your sub saveXL()

```
Sub SaveXL()
    Dim Nom2 As String
    Dim Jour2 As String
    Dim FPath2 As String
    Jour2 = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd - h\hmm'")
    Nom2 = Jour2 & " Pricelist"
    FPath2 = Sheets("PARAM").Range("B33").Value
    On Error GoTo fin4
    fichier = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FPath2 & Nom2, "Fichiers Excel (*.xls), *.xls")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs fichier
    call test(ActiveWorkbook) '<-- here you use your Test() sub
    Exit Sub
    fin4:MsgBox "La création de l'excel a échoué"
End Sub
```

P.S.: Sorry my English